# Chrome Extension - Create tab with callback function crashes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a new tab in a chrome extension like the code given below, but it crashes the browser. However, when I do not use the callback function, it works fine.

```
chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'https://google.com'}, function(tab){ alert(tab.id) })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to correct your url. It should be

```
http://www.google.com
```

You can refer to

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html